# Error while running Spring Cloud Functions sample for Azure functions

Tags: azure-functions, azure-functions-runtime, azure-functions-core-tools

I am experimenting with Spring Cloud Functions on top of Azure Functions, and while I was trying to run a sample project for azure functions I came across the following error.

```
 Executed 'Functions.uppercase' (Failed, Id=4fd6ef4c-209c-45cb-bf65-ce38e90b6620)
 System.Private.CoreLib: Exception while executing function: Functions.uppercase. System.Private.CoreLib: Result: Failure
 Exception: ClassCastException: com.microsoft.azure.functions.worker.binding.RpcHttpRequestDataSource cannot be cast to java.lang.String
 Stack: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.microsoft.azure.functions.worker.binding.RpcHttpRequestDataSource cannot be cast to java.lang.String
   at com.microsoft.azure.functions.worker.binding.DataOperations.apply(DataOperations.java:91)
   at com.microsoft.azure.functions.worker.binding.DataSource.computeByType(DataSource.java:56)
   at com.microsoft.azure.functions.worker.binding.RpcHttpRequestDataSource.computeByType(RpcHttpRequestDataSource.java:20)
   at com.microsoft.azure.functions.worker.binding.DataSource.computeByName(DataSource.java:42)
   at com.microsoft.azure.functions.worker.binding.RpcHttpRequestDataSource.computeByName(RpcHttpRequestDataSource.java:20)
   at com.microsoft.azure.functions.worker.binding.BindingDataStore.getDataByName(BindingDataStore.java:50)
   at com.microsoft.azure.functions.worker.broker.ParameterResolver.resolve(ParameterResolver.java:59)
   at com.microsoft.azure.functions.worker.broker.ParameterResolver.resolve(ParameterResolver.java:42)
   at com.microsoft.azure.functions.worker.broker.JavaMethodExecutor.execute(JavaMethodExecutor.java:52)
   at com.microsoft.azure.functions.worker.broker.JavaFunctionBroker.invokeMethod(JavaFunctionBroker.java:51)
   at com.microsoft.azure.functions.worker.handler.InvocationRequestHandler.execute(InvocationRequestHandler.java:33)
   at com.microsoft.azure.functions.worker.handler.InvocationRequestHandler.execute(InvocationRequestHandler.java:10)
   at com.microsoft.azure.functions.worker.handler.MessageHandler.handle(MessageHandler.java:45)
   at com.microsoft.azure.functions.worker.JavaWorkerClient$StreamingMessagePeer.lambda$onNext$0(JavaWorkerClient.java:92)
   at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
 .
```

Sample project link on github
https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-function/tree/master/spring-cloud-function-samples/function-sample-azure

```
public class FooHandler extends AzureSpringBootRequestHandler<Foo, Bar> {
    @FunctionName("uppercase")
    public Bar execute(
            @HttpTrigger(name = "req", methods = { HttpMethod.GET,
                    HttpMethod.POST }, authLevel = AuthorizationLevel.ANONYMOUS) Foo foo,
            ExecutionContext context) {
        return handleRequest(foo, context);
    }  
}
```

Azure local runtime version 2 (Fails in Azure as well)

```
Azure Functions Core Tools (2.3.199 Commit hash: fdf734b09806be822e7d946fe17928b419d8a289)
Function Runtime Version: 2.0.12246.0
```

As there's nothing related to Spring Cloud in the stack-trace, I suppose this is related to Azure. Would appreciate any help.

Comment: The error pretty clearly states that `com.microsoft.azure.functions.worker.binding.RpcHttpRequestDataSource cannot be cast to java.lang.String`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at this issue on GitHub: [byte[] input broken](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-java-worker/issues/239).

> Thank you reporting. This is a regression. As a workaround, please use `java.lang.Byte[]` instead of `byte[]`

Looks like it has been fixed:

> [pragnagopa](https://github.com/pragnagopa) closed this in [#241](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-java-worker/pull/241) on Nov 14, 2018

Comment: Thanks rickvdbosch, but the error I have seems to be  https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-java-worker/issues/255. I am using a HttpTrigger.

Comment: pragnagopa has fixed the issue with HttpTrigger as well. https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-java-worker/issues/239#issuecomment-438808074

Answer (score 0):

The sample code given at https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-function/tree/master/spring-cloud-function-samples/function-sample-azure has some issues.

The type of first parameter should be `HttpRequestMessage<Optional<Foo>>` and not `Foo`.

```
@FunctionName("uppercase")
    public Bar execute(
        @HttpTrigger(name = "req", methods = {HttpMethod.GET,
            HttpMethod.POST}, authLevel = AuthorizationLevel.ANONYMOUS) HttpRequestMessage<Optional<Foo>> fooHttp,
        ExecutionContext context) {
        Foo foo = fooHttp.getBody().get();
        return handleRequest(foo, context);
    }
```

Also the version of `spring-cloud-function-dependencies` had to be changed to `2.0.1.RELEASE`.

`mvn clean package azure-functions:run` was then running the code correctly for me.